# Insect Identification (even the family name would do)

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

I found this insect in Bhopal,Madhya Pradesh,India could you please help me identify it??
I think it is some kind of beetle. Approximately 2-3 cm in size.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology. SE! Thanks for taking the tour before posting. From the wing case, it looks like a true bug (Hemiptera). Any chance you can add something to show the scale?

Comment: I am sorry I can't add anything to add to show the scale as I was just passing by when I saw it,but I suppose it was 2-3 cms besause if the size of the leaf which seen in the photo.

Comment: I suppose it belongs to superfamily Pentatomoidea.

Comment: That's a hemipteran not a coleoptera

Answer (score 3):

You've found a specimen of Coridius janus or cucurbit stink bug or red pumpkin bug (don't mix up with the red pumpkin beetle). They betong to the suborder [Heteroptera](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroptera) (True bugs).

[image]
(picturefrom Wikipedia)

Also see:
[projectnoah.org: red pumpkin bug](http://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/89196024)

[nbair.res.in: Coridius janus](http://www.nbair.res.in/insectpests/Coridius-janus.php)

[indiabiodiversity.org: Coridius janus](http://indiabiodiversity.org/observation/show/269493)

Comment: It would be nice if you could embed at least one image of the proposed ID in your response, instead of just providing links to those images.

Comment: We really discourage linking to pictures or any other valuable info off of SO because if the link dies (which it often does), your answer becomes useless to future viewers. So, to follow up Charles's comment, please make sure your answer here on SO is as complete as possible without requiring users to visit external links